# Getting error while uploading JSON File in XRAY Test Execution to generate final Report

Tags: selenium, cucumber, jira

A JSON file is generated(at the specified location) when a Cucumber Runner is executed as a "JUNIT File".I am trying to upload this JSON file in XRAY Test Execution to generate final Report.I am getting the below error,

"Error Importing Execution Results

Error parsing file to json object. - Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: I believe that the JSON file is not in proper format. Is it possible for you to update your question with the sample JSON file?

Comment: Ok I will do it.

Comment: The JSON is file is large in Size.How can I send you the JSON...?